# how to replace a value based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to replace '-' with the value in the same row.

This is my original df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1','-','-','4','5'], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df
```

But then how do I get to the result df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1','6','7','4','5'], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` for converting `-` to `NaN` and `bfill()` on `axis=1`:

```
df=df.replace('-',float('NaN')).bfill(axis=1)
#df.replace('-',float('NaN')).bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1)
```

OR

via `replace()` and Transpose(`T`) attribute

```
df=df.T.replace('-',method='bfill').T
```

output of `df`:

```
    A   B
0   1   5
1   6   6
2   7   7
3   4   8
4   5   9
```